# How to specify which pages NOT to print in PDF?

Tags: pdf, printing

I know that you can specify which pages to print using this example notation, `1-5,7,9-12`. In this scenario I'm printing pages 1-12 except page 6 & 8. Is it possible to tell the print dialog the opposite? Like print everything except 6 & 8? I've tried this notation `!6,!8` but that didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More tech support than UX, but you can open the PDF in Acrobat, select all pages (in page view) then command-click the pages you don't want to print.

Comment: Sorry I did not know where to post this question. Oh so I guess it's impossible to specify a type of format in that *Pages* Input box?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, yes, although looking around it seems it's been requested for some time. If I were to design a notation for it, I would probably use "!": so to print all except pages 3 and 11-14, "!3, !11-14" in the pages field.

Comment: Yeah I'd probably also use that notation! thank you! i close this question then :)